# "By which" vs "for which" usage

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

Can "by which" be equivalent to "for which", for example in this quote?

> Stripped of this anthropological association, the word
> *on* is indistinguishable from the word ‘under’ or the word ‘beside’.
> Even if the universal form of space is that without which there would
> be for us no bodily space, it is not that **by which** there is one. [Taken from: Part 1, Ch. 3 in Merleau-Ponty, M., & Smith, C. (2002). *Phenomenology of Perception*. Routledge. (p. 116)]

Furthermore, may I replace "by which" with "for which" under any circumstance without changing the meaning of what's stated/asked?

Comment: No, you *can't* treat ***by which*** and ***for which*** as interchangeable in the cited context. I'm not sure you can *ever* do that with the 2-word collocations, but there may be other contexts where the choice of ***by*** or ***for*** makes little or no difference. Specifically in *this* context, we're told the "universal form of space" (whatever *that* means! :) is ***not*** what gives ***us*** "bodily space" (again, meaningless to me). But ***for which*** would mean the "universal form of space" doesn't have ***its own*** "bodily space". It's hardly a suitable text for *learners*, though,

Comment: No, **by which** I mean you can't replace one with the other and still get the same meaning or even a meaningful  sentence.

Comment: @PeterJennings: Yes, **for which** I'll give your comment an upvote! :)

Comment: What about _without which_?

Comment: @JohnLawler **without which** this list is incomplete.

Comment: @JohnLawler: To my ear, this text is barely "English" in the first place. So I have to put on my "programmer's hat" and treat it as a bunch of algebraic symbols glued together by a few "operators" (prepositions and such). If we change OP's highlighted element to repeat previously-used ***without which***, we get *even if it's something] **without which** [we wouldn't have bodily space], it is NOT something **without which** there is bodily space*. (Which imho means even ***less**!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "symbols glued together by a few 'operators' " is a very concise description of what utterances are. I agree completely. How come nobody's mentioned Pied Piping? It's the presenting complaint -- these are not phrases, they're constructions with rules and variation.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Way back when I was a teenager (having just attended my first term's linguistics lectures as an undergraduate), I returned to my family for Xmas and offered up the proposition that it's not possible to ***think*** something if you don't have ***words*** for it. I don't remember if I got that from the lecturer himself (probably *not*), but I still remember how vehemently all my family rejected the proposition. *And* I still believe it - without words and symbols manipulated in the context of "rules", all we have are relatively formless ***emotions***.

Comment: Many people seem to think in words, others in pictures. This probly accounts for a great deal of human confusion. I used to believe that I thought in words, but over the years I have realized that I'm so curious about language because I don't think with words; I think about words because they're so strange.

Comment: @JohnLawler : Unlike FumbleFingers you are not very cognate with Merleau-Ponty. I'd reccomend you to read "The World of Perception", his easiest book to start understanding his thought.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and could you indicate what is English? You should read MP too

Comment: @tac Thank you. I'd recommend you to read [Fillmore's Deixis Lectures](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html). They point to the extreme difference between what humans actually do and what they think they do.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I've never been a great fan of Chomsky - and I'm well aware it's a bit much the likes of me opining on such matters to the likes of you - but I couldn't resist coming back here after just chancing upon Chomsky saying [*language is a core part of human cognition, **it's language that constructs thoughts***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LzZGLADCEw). And since *Closer To Truth* Youtube presenter Robert Kuhn chose to copy just those few words as a lead-in to his post, I guess *he* agrees with that too. But I sure wish I could think in pictures *as well!*